# Google Visualizations (Charts) API: Change which axis the legend uses?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/1cLpukxx/1/

As you can see, the legend is the `Density` value. I think that's because all I'm doing is this:

```
legend: { position: "right" }
```

I'd like the legend to be the elements, with the colour that they are in the charts.

I feel like this should be easy, however I haven't found it in any examples (using the x-axis legend as the side-legend). I feel like this is because I don't know what to search for but I digress...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [style column](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) used in the example overrides the legend, which is why the position is set to --> `'none'`

One option would be to change the rows to columns, as in the following example.
This creates separate series and allows setting an array for `colors` in the configuration options.
However, this causes other issues, such as the spacing of the columns.

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Metal", "Copper", "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum"],
    ["Copper", 8.94, null, null, null],
    ["Silver", null, 10.49,  null,  null],
    ["Gold",  null,  null, 19.30,  null],
    ["Platinum",  null,  null,  null, 21.45]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([
    0,
    1, {calc: "stringify",
     sourceColumn: 1,
     type: "string",
     role: "annotation"},
    2, {calc: "stringify",
     sourceColumn: 2,
     type: "string",
     role: "annotation"},
    3, {calc: "stringify",
     sourceColumn: 3,
     type: "string",
     role: "annotation"},
    4, {calc: "stringify",
     sourceColumn: 4,
     type: "string",
     role: "annotation"},
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    legend: {alignment: "right"},
    colors: ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', '#e5e4e2']
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, that got me where I needed to go! I changed the datatable to be this: 

`var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Metal", "Copper", "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum"],
    ["Metal", 8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45]
]);`

And that worked for my purposes.